# How do I fix the delay on my Razer Naga's buttons?

Tags: peripherals, razer-mouse

I'm not sure if this is the correct site to post it on, but I'm having problems with my Razer Naga Epic.

I took a break for about a week, and when I went to use my Naga Epic all the buttons, left click, right click, side buttons, everything are delayed by about 5-10 seconds.

I can move the mouse pointer around fine, there's no delay there, but the buttons take 5-10 seconds to register.

I've tried it on multiple computers and operating system, nothing different.

I've tried taking the battery out, wired, wireless and nothing has fixed it, there's nothing on the Razer site about it and I've found nothing on Google.

I've even tried throwing the piece of crap against the wall and still nothing, and yes I really did throw it against the wall, however it hit a music CD case and broke it, the mouse if fine other than the buttons still being delayed by 5-10 seconds.

I am being 100% serious about this problem, does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: I have no problems with other mice, wired or wireless.

Comment: Have you tried updating the fimrware? http://www.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=519

Comment: It's already up-to-date, both firmware and drivers, tried with and without drivers, even reinstalling the drivers.

Comment: How about increasing the polling rate? If that doesn't do it, it's probably something with the mouse itself since you say the problem travels with the mouse on different computers. Could try re-updating the firmware, but I'm not sure if their app will let you do that.

Comment: Polling rate didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I finally had enough of the mouse and ended up throwing it against the wall hard enough to break it into pieces.

[image: Razer Naga Not-so-EPIC]

Comment: All i have to say is "Ouch"

Comment: So, the mouse was out of warranty? Otherwise this is quite a shame...

Comment: Anger problems? I feel bad for the thing...

Comment: well...that's a rather unique "answer".

Comment: This is the coolest self-answer I've ever seen.

Comment: You feel bad for the misbehaving mouse, @sinni800? I feel bad for the _wall_.

Comment: @LordTorgamus yeah, yeah I do. I always feel bad when electronics are smacked apart. I don't know why

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the mouse does this is because it enters sleep mode when it stops moving, it seems that in your case the timer is affected which makes it enter sleep mode way too fast. For the device to return from sleep mode it has to reconnect Bluetooth, which can indeed take 5-10 seconds.

Take the warranty road, or send it in for a repair. But it seems that you decided to break it instead...

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted to throw this against the wall like you did, but after constantly reinstalling the drivers. I decided to:

- Uninstall all
- Delete from registry
- Update from the website

This seems to do the trick, at least for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Was getting a couple seconds of delay on the 12 side buttons of my Razer Naga Chroma(2-3+ years old).

Unplugged my mouse and plugged it back in, no longer getting lag.

Answer (score 0):

I unplugged the mouse and removed the side panel, put the side panel back and plugged the mouse back in. Seemed to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this could be something to do with Razer Cortex. So, if by any chance you are using razer cortex. Disable it, and see if that fixes it. I had a similar issue with my razer keyboard and this fixed it fine.